# Checking if the points fall within circleS

Tags: python, pandas, list, coordinates, point

I have a long list of `H-points` with known coordinates. I have also a list of `TP-points`. I'd like to know if the `H-points` fall within any(!) `TP-point` with certain radius (e.g. `r=5`).

```
dfPoints = pd.DataFrame({'H-points' : ['a','b','c','d','e'],
               'Xh' :[10, 35, 52, 78, 9],
               'Yh' : [15,5,11,20,10]})

dfTrafaPostaje = pd.DataFrame({'TP-points' : ['a','b','c','d','e'],
               'Xt' :[15,25,35],
               'Yt' : [15,25,35],
               'M' : [5,2,3]})

def inside_circle(x, y, a, b, r):
    return (x - a)*(x - a) + (y - b)*(y - b) < r*r
```

I've started but.. it would be much easier to check this for only one TP point. But if I have e.g. 1500 of them and 30.000 H-points, then i need more general solution.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use `distance_matrix` from `scipy.spatial`:

```
dist_mat = distance_matrix(dfPoints [['Xh','Yh']], dfTrafaPostaje [['Xt','Yt']])
dfPoints [np.min(dist_mat,axis=1)<5]
```

Took about 2s for `1500 dfPoints` and `30000 dfTrafaPostje`.

---

**Update**: to get the index of the reference points with highest score:

```
dist_mat = distance_matrix(dfPoints [['Xh','Yh']], dfTrafaPostaje [['Xt','Yt']])

# get the M scores of those within range
M_mat = pd.DataFrame(np.where(dist_mat <= 5, dfTrafaPosaje['M'].values[None, :], np.nan),
                     index=dfPoints['H-points'] ,
                     columns=dfTrafaPostaje['TP-points'])

# get the points with largest M values
# mask with np.nan for those outside range    
dfPoints['M'] = np.where(M_mat.notnull().any(1), M_mat.idxmax(1), np.nan)
```

For the included sample data:

```
  H-points  Xh  Yh   TP
0        a  10  15    a
1        b  35   5  NaN
2        c  52  11  NaN
3        d  78  20  NaN
4        e   9  10  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! To go one step further, would be possible to add to final output the name of the TP-point that falls within radius?

Comment: Yes, but one point may be within several circles, how do you want them?

Comment: I added ´ M´ column in ´dfTrafaPostaje ´ - if it's possible, if one H point falls within many TP, it goes under TP with the biggest M value

Comment: The solution works great for the min distance between points. But as I said, I added a column M in the origin question with some values. How would this be done, if i'd like to connect the TP point with the biggest values of M in the given radius?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) from scipy to compute the pairwise distances, then create a mask with True where distance is less than radius, and finally filter:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

dfPoints = pd.DataFrame({'H-points': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
                         'Xh': [10, 35, 52, 78, 9],
                         'Yh': [15, 5, 11, 20, 10]})

dfTrafaPostaje = pd.DataFrame({'TP-points': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                               'Xt': [15, 25, 35],
                               'Yt': [15, 25, 35]})

radius = 5
distances = cdist(dfPoints[['Xh', 'Yh']].values, dfTrafaPostaje[['Xt', 'Yt']].values, 'sqeuclidean')
mask = (distances <= radius*radius).sum(axis=1) > 0 # create mask

print(dfPoints[mask])
```

**Output**

```
  H-points  Xh  Yh
0        a  10  15
```

Comment: Thanks! Very elegant solution! To go one step further, would be possible to add to final output the name of the TP-point that falls within radius?